# Is it possible to run ad-hoc code against the current editor in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to run some code to manipulate text in the editor of VSCode.  Is there a way to do this without creating a new extension?

Comment: what kind of manipulations do you want?

Comment: For example, text processing, calling template generators with a custom generated list of data based on the content of various files either in the folder tree or from some other resources.

Comment: which functions of VSC do you want to use that you don't have in a Python script or Node script?

Comment: I want to use the VS Code APIs to navigate various collections it provides, utilize its search engine, invoke commands and other things that can only be done 8n the editor.  I want to write scripts to repeat the operations.

Comment: I'm thinking that a shim layer between the JS APIs and .Net Core would allow you to access the editor's API from the powershell console.

Comment: So I've started an extension to do this and it's working for both Javascript and TypeScript in unit tests.  I am abled to use the full VSCode object model from the scripts and work with the output of commands.